# How to prevent an empty img element from shrinkage?

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, size

- I have an `<img>` element (an upload image preview frame) whose `scr` will be set by javascript,
- So when it is initially loaded, it has no image in it, I have set its `width` and `height` properties by css to maintain its size and position at startup (In fact, it is a hint for user to know what is the proper aspect ratio for the desired image).
- This code behave well in IE and Chrome, but the problem is that Firefox does not keep the frame's initial size (when empty) and shrinks to zero size.

**How can I overcome this issue?**

Code:

```
 <img width="90" height="120" class="uploadPreview" id="Preview_pic" >
```

css:

```
 img.uploadPreview {
    width:90px;
    height:120px;
    border-style:groove;
}
```

thank you very much!

Comment: I'm guessing that FF doesn't render it, since it has no source. Maybe if you add an alternative text (`alt="Image placeholder"`) it will show in the right dimension.

Comment: This is how I do it, [**placehold.it**](http://placehold.it/), I prefer to have an image in there, placehold.it is built to do that. Just an idea for you anyway. Even better for you it says the size.

Comment: I added an alt, but it does not show the borders with proper sizes, it just shows the alt text with a tight box around it:  <img alt="Users Picture" width="90" height="120" class="uploadPreview" id="Preview_pic" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the shrinking by making the `<img>` `display:block;` or `display: inline-block;`

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sp8n67u1/1/**

```
img.uploadPreview {
    width:90px;
    height:120px;
    border-style:groove;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: it worked by using inline-block. I also added an alt attribute. thank you for your precious help